# Spring: Autowired or "Plain" Call by using the @Configuration annotations?

Tags: spring, autowired

i have the following JAVA supported in Spring 4.0.3 configuration, that have two DataSource und JdbcTemplate beans:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {
.....
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource internalDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

// init dataSource  setters for DATABASE_1

        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource publicDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

// init dataSource  setters for DATABASE_2

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

...
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate internalJDBCTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(internalDataSource());
    }

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate publicJDBCTemplate() {
    return new JdbcTemplate(publicDataSource());
}
___
```

I have other configuration bean class, that autowires the first configuration and calls internalDataSource() method:

```
    @Import(DBConfiguration.class)
    @Configuration

 public class AuthConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private DBConfiguration dbConfiguration;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

       @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dbConfiguration.securityDataSource());
        }
...}
```

I suppose, that even DBConfiguration was imported and autowired into AuthConfiguration class, the each call of dbConfiguration.securityDataSource() will be cause the new DriverManagerDataSource() with each time intializing of data source.

Is it correkt or not?

Answer (score 1):

The default bean scope in Spring is singleton so the data source will be initialized only once.

When a DI container creates bean **TokenStore** it gets a bean defined in **DBConfiguration** by the **securityDataSource** method. But it doesn't call the method directly, it takes a bean instance from the DI container. An initialization of all beans is done by Spring transparently to a developer.

Note that classes annotated with **@Configuration** are just a definition for the framework and they aren't executed directly.

Comment: If i use the "classic" singleton (for example on enum basis),
the call of such methods , that have "new" operator causes each time the creation of new object. What differend in spring?

Comment: Spring parses configuration classes with usage of the reflection. Beans managed by Spring aren't classic singletons. They are ordinary classes. Spring is responsible to manage their scopes.